# Keep getting semaphore compile problem can someone help me?

Tags: semaphore

Im trying to compile program with semaphores but i keep getting errors like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pQMI.png

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
gcc <inputfile.c> -o <outputfile> -lpthread -lrt
```